# How to encrypt sensitive info on exec line in .desktop shortcut?

Tags: encryption, shortcuts, .desktop

One of my custom shortcut has auto login parameter along with my login credential in clear text on the exec line. Is there trick how to write the login details portion in encrypted form and make Ubuntu prompts for password or something to decrypt it when I launch the shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this is not generally possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/can-other-users-view-the-arguments-passed-to-a-command).

> "In general, command line arguments are visible to all."

Unless the program in question is willing to accept encrypted passwords as command-line arguments, then you must either supply the password in plaintext or omit it entirely.

Some common applications provide an option for prompting the user for their password immediately. For example, the [`mysql` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mysql) offers the `-p` option:

> "If you omit the password value following the `--password` or `-p` option on the command line, mysql prompts for one."

Comment: ah you're right about that! it didn't occur me to me that the command arg will globally appear in process list when you pass the password in plain text